# Can't generate a new migration in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to generate a new migration to add an Index to a table field with the following :

> $ rails generate migration AddIndexToUserEmail

Though, unexpectedly I get the following message

> C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/formatters/b
>   ase_formatter.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant
>   RSpec::Support (NameError)
>           from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-legacy_formatters-1.0.0/l
>   ib/rspec/legacy_formatters.rb:24:in`require'
>           from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-legacy_formatters-1.0.0/l
>   ib/rspec/legacy_formatters.rb:24:in `block in <top (required)>'
>           from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-legacy_formatters-1.0.0/l
>   ib/rspec/legacy_formatters.rb:13:in`each'
>           from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-legacy_formatters-1.0.0/l
>   ib/rspec/legacy_formatters.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
>           from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runti
>   me.rb:81:in`require'
>           from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runti
>   me.rb:81:in `rescue in block in require'
>           from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runti
>   me.rb:66:in`block in require'
>           from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runti
>   me.rb:59:in `each'
>           from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runti
>   me.rb:59:in`require'
>           from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:13
>   2:in `require'
>           from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/comman
>   ds.rb:43:in`require'
>           from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/comman
>   ds.rb:43:in `<top (required)>'
>           from bin/rails:4:in`require'
>           from bin/rails:4:in `'

I am not sure what has to be understood here as I had same Constant Unitinialized error when trying to do tests with RSPEC (before I found the right setup). 
Though this is a different context here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems the problem was coming from the following gem:

`gem "rspec-legacy_formatters", :group => [:development, :test]`

Not sure why I added it to the gem file. I removed it and did a

```
$ bundle install
```

which solved the problem